# Inserting a single record into AWS elasticsearch service using index method is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch

I am trying to insert single record into my AWS elastic search service. I am using the official @elastic/elasticsearch npm module.

Here is my sample code:

```
const { Client } = require('@elastic/elasticsearch')
const { createAWSConnection, awsCredsifyAll, awsGetCredentials } = require('@acuris/aws-es-connection')
const { elasticSearchHost } = require('./config')

const getClient = async () => {
  const awsCredentials = await awsGetCredentials()
  const Connection = createAWSConnection(awsCredentials)

  return awsCredsifyAll(new Client({ node: elasticSearchHost, Connection }))
}

const insert = async () => {
  const esClient = await getClient()
  const response = await esClient.index({
    index: 'someIndex',
    id: '1234',
    body: { name: 'Joe', age: 22 }
  })
}

insert()
```

But I am always getting a very not so helpful error like this

```
ERROR   Invoke Error    
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "ResponseError: Response Error",
    "stack": [
        "Error: ResponseError: Response Error",
        "    at Function.exports.execute (/var/task/src/processor.js:27:11)",
        "    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)"
    ]
}
```

client.index works when I run elastic search service locally. Not sure if AWS service supports it. If not then is there any other way/method I can use to insert a single record into AWS elastic search service.

Comment: You can rule out AWS not supporting basic Elasticsearch functionality. If I had to guess, you have an authentication problem. The Elasticsearch SDK gives you a lot of options for tying into the request/response handler, but I'd start by using a logging proxy (or, if you're running in the browser, take a look at the Network tab).

Comment: @Parsifal thanks for the suggestion. But the issue was basically I was using our in-house custom logger which I recently got to know logs only the main error and not the metadata associated with it. And most of the errors of elastic search contains a vague main error message and a detailed message in its metadata.
Relevant GitHub Issue Blog: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-
js/blob/f7be49f2bafa3b9ddc90b0caac5b70932e6db35b/lib/errors.js#L71-L94

Comment: I gave POST and GET access to elastic search but missed PUT which was causing the problem